# Garbage characters in approved Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to solve a mystery here... Submitted an extension update and it was approved last night and I rolled it out shortly after. I discovered that a JS error was thrown in the newly rolled out release...

> Invalid or unexpected token

This error was not thrown in the build submitted for review. After inspecting the compiled js in the rolled out version, I discovered a bunch of garbage characters that were not present in the uploaded extension...

[image]

I'm wondering if the extension was got corrupted in the review process? Has this happened to anyone else? I've submitted a new build for review with no changes and am hoping that this one will not have these garbage characters.

[image]

Comment: I don;t know what a garage character is but they look like nul-bytes to me. I would hazard a guess that the file has been converted from the character-set you uploaded it as to something else, most probably a difference between BOM UTF-8 and er, other UTF-8, but this is a guess so far...

Comment: ‍♂️ I meant "garbage" characters, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Someone don't want to admit it, but it happens more than you want to believe.

There are certain characters that are not always digested by the publication / review process.
The same character once passes and another time it gets busted.
It happened to me with the character §
In short, I suggest you to avoid these characters or use their escape sequence instead (i.e. `space = &nbsp; = &#32;`)
If this translation has had persistent implications, such as having incorrectly set items of some storage system (localStorage, chrome.storage indexedDB etc.), after replacing your character with the corresponding escape sequence, you will also have to try to put a patch on it to restore the expected value of such variables \ objects.
In my specific case I had to insert some code inside the onInstalled event handler checking if the user is updating from that "faulty" version.

Comment: So bizarre! The nul-byte block in the compiled JS very large (thousands of characters). Was this what it looks like for you? (see the new screenshot in the question)

Comment: I guess you see this null-byte block in devtools source panel.
Have you checked if the uploaded zip file contains the right characters?

Comment: Yea, I see the null-bytes in the release published to the Webstore when inspecting with devtools. The uploaded zip does not contain null-byte characters

Comment: The scrambled block is the product of **1.** a single char repeated many time or **2.** a string made by different characters?
If the answer is **1** what should be the right char?
Also, the block is addded to the normal code flow or replace an old one?

Comment: It's just normal minified code to the right. It's cutting off "webpack_require"

Comment: Not quite the problem I had.
Yours is perhaps more serious.
have you tried reporting this thing [here](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/one_stop_support?visit_id=637981027521380413-2518068856&rd=1) ?

Comment: Shoot, still appreciate your help! I did create a ticket there